# Is it possible to automatically log in to link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, basic-authentication

I want to link to a page and when the user clicks on the link his username and password are already there for him. However where i am linking too i don't control that pages code.

Is it possible to have my javascript execute there after the user clicks the link?

```
$("#link").click(function() {
 alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
 var username = getCookie("username");
    var password = getCookie("password");
    var usernameTextBox = document.getElementById("j_username");
    var passwordTextBox = document.getElementById("j_password");
     usernameTextBox.value = username;
     passwordTextBox.value = password;
 });
```

[See my JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo38x6po/1/)

Comment: at least comment on a down-vote saying what else you were looking for me to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually execute it from another page, you can however use the following.

The best way to do this is with a cookie, storing the username, and pointing to an encrypted file with an encrypted password. But you can store the encrypted password in a cookie too, as long as it's encrypted before putting it in the cookie.

*I originally developed this for a function  that will keep a user logged in to a page that redirected to a login whenever it is accessed, it will click the button and bring them to the page after the login page.*

working example: ***Will need to be edited to fit exact elements on any page, and run on the page, probally through a property or permission gained through a download or web app etc.***

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function stayLoggedIn() {
    setCookie("logged_in","true",30);
    setCookie("username", username,30);
    setCookie("password",encryptedPassword,30);
    return null;
}
window.onload {
    var loggedIn = getCookie("logged_in");
    if(loggedIn == true) {
        var username = getCookie("username");
        var password = getCookie("password");
        var usernameTextBox = document.getElementById("username");
        var passwordTextBox = document.getElementById("password");
//decrypt password here.
        usernameTextBox.value = username;
        passwordTextBox.value = password;
    }
    else {}
}
```

Explained:

first, we set a function to set a cookie and get one, I took these from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
then, I set the function `stayLoggedIn()` this sets the cookie with the value of `"logged_in"` to `true`, so when the user comes to the page, and `window.onload` runs it's block, the `if` statement is triggered, and the username and password fields are filled in.
Then, `click(element)` is called on the logginButton, this can click on php, or html buttons or submit forms etc. This simulates the button being clicked, and the user logging in.

Also: You need to call the function `stayLoggedIn()` *after* the link is clicked (like through a google or  firefox extension)

Comment: ok so use window.onload to put these values into that area of the form and submit because that happens after link is rendered right?

Comment: @BobSinclar Yeah, because otherwise it would put them into uncreated boxes because the page loads in order as read on the html document, so <head><script src="blablabla"></script></head> is read before <body></body> and window.onload only runs after all documents have fully loaded.

Comment: in the original post (i dont think i worded the question right)